# TikTok video embedding does not work on Angular 13

Tags: html, angular, tiktok

On my app, I am trying to embed a TikTok video in the following format.

index.html file's `head`:

```
<script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

TS file's `ngOnInit`:

```js
            const videoUrl = //arbitrary url
            const tiktokRes: any =
                await lastValueFrom(
                    this.http.get(`https://www.tiktok.com/oembed?url=${videoUrl}`)
                );
    
            if (!tiktokRes) { return; }
    
            this.videoHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
                (tiktokRes['html'] as string)
            );
            this.showVideo = true;
```

and my HTML as follow:

```
<mat-tab label="Video" *ngIf="showVideo">
  <div [innerHtml]="videoHtml"></div>
</mat-tab>
```

This is my current result (blank TikTok section, video not loaded at all)

[image]

What do I do to get this to work? I've browsed all other StackOverflow questions regarding this topic but **none** of the answers worked.